# it is impossible to hide status background when i'm using UITabbar in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm using UITab bar. In my UITabbar have 4 items and each of tabbar have navigation controller.

i want to put gradient color in the status background of view controller in 1-3 items but in view controller 4 i want it to have a status clear background.

my problem is when i go to tab 1-3 and then go to tab 4 the status background color will change according to the of tab 1-3. But I want the status background color of tab 4 is transparent.

the code that I use to change color of status background in tab 1-3

```
if let status = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView {
            status.setGradientBackground(colorOne: Colors.carmine, colorTwo: Colors.cherryRed, colorThree: Colors.cherryRedTwo)
        }
```

I have tried to hide status bar in Tab 4 by this method

1.change View controller-based status bar appearance to YES

2.put

```
setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

in viewdidload

3.put

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
```

in viewdidappear but still not work background of status bar is not hidding and the status background color still change according to the of tab 1-3.

it have one method that work by using this code

```
UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
```

and put it in every view controller

but it have warning like this

```
Setter for 'isStatusBarHidden' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController prefersStatusBarHidden]
```

I want to know the correct way to change color of the status bar in UITab Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if I understand what you want correctly, you want to make your tab 4 to have a clear status bar, here's what you can try if your main view in tab 4,  has subviews. Once you change your main view color, the status bar color changes also :

```
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

     if let lastTab = tabBarController?.children[3] {
        lastTab.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white // status bar will be clear

    }
 }
```